# Position Element to a specifc continer CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I have 3 containers.

The **Yellow box** is standard HTML

The **Brown box** is a container within the HTML

The **Red box** is an another container that appears at the very bottom of an HTML.

I can't change *any* HTML, because it's being processed via PHP's `readfile`. However, I can add CSS to the yellow box.

I want to possition the red box inside of the brown box as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `position: absolute` on the red box?

Something like:

```
#red-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

(numbers would need tweaking...)

Comment: i tryied doing that but it changes depending on the users screen size

Answer (score 0):

as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="yellow">

  <div class="brown"></div>

  <div class="red"></div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.yellow{
background:yellow;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin-top:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.brown{
background:pink;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.red{
background:red;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-90px;
  margin-left:-90px;

}
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/zdaCyo5l